# Japanese is not displayed in PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services

I have a generated PDF file with Japaneses text I use [Arial Unicode MS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS) as a font some letters displayed correctly but for others I see gibrish like this 〠ぇ》❥ (hope you can see it)

How do I get it to display Japanese characters instead?

Comment: How is this programming related?  Most likely you need to install a language pack or change the internationalization settings on your computer, something of that nature.

Comment: It generated with MS reporting services

Comment: You might want to include that little tidbit in your question or the tags.  Do you have any code you can show us?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Arial Unicode MS has 2 different version 0.84 and 1.01 the later has a better support for Japanese